# Get value from <Html input form> in Visual Basisc

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

i am try to scrape some data from an html page.
I am scraping using Excel Macros and Vba.

This is my code

```
'Prendo i dati dalla pagina
Set Table = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("smart-form")  'Prendo la tabella
Set rows= Table(0).getElementsByTagName("div")             'Prendo le righe della tabella
Set column = raws(0).getElementsByTagName("section")

Set codAWP = column(1).getElementsByTagName("input").value
```

The error is 438 Object does not support propriety ot methods

And this is the html

```html
<form action="" class="smart-form">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class="row">                                        <section class="col col-2"><label class="input">CODEID</label></section>
                                        <section class="col col-4"><label class="input"><input type="text" readonly value="RN05304485B"></label></section>
```

The value i need is RN05304485B

Comment: Your code needs to be a complete minimal example not just the snippet you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using getAttribute instead jus value

```
'Prendo i dati dalla pagina
Set Table = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("smart-form")  'Prendo la tabella
Set righe = Table(0).getElementsByTagName("div")             'Prendo le righe della tabella
Set colonna = righe(0).getElementsByClassName("col col-4")


Cells(7, 1).Value = ((Trim(colonna(0).getElementsByTagName("input")(0).getAttribute("value")))) 'AWP
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with more concise css selector

```
Activesheet.Cells(7, 1).Value = ie.document.querySelector(".smart-form input").value
```